# Axes in XSLT template match

Tags: xslt, xpath, axes

I want a template match like this:

```
<xsl:template match="//content[parent::(@type='async')]">
 <table>
  <thead>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="row[@type='header']" />
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/row[@type='data']" />
  </tbody>
 </table>
</xsl:template>
```

With this XML:

```
<document type="async">
 <content>
  <!-- Some rows with types -->
 </content>
</document>
```

My problem is the `<xsl:template match="//content[parent::(@type='async')]">`, how do I make this work?

Comment: Since the syntax is invalid, how are we supposed to know what you want it to do? We can't be expected to work out your requirements from reading a program that doesn't meet them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
//content[parent::*/@type='async']
```

which can be shortened to:

```
//content[../@type='async']
```

Here's another:

```
//*[@type='async']/content
```

**Note**:
In general, it's always best to be explicit and avoid the `*` notation if you know the element's name (`document` in this case), and particularly the `//` symbol if you know the exact path.

Specifically, in a match pattern a leading `//` is redundant because a template will be automatically applied if (and only if) the pattern is matched in the course of traversing the input tree.

Comment: In a pattern any leading `//` can also be removed.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks, I was concentrating too much on the general XPath aspect, and lost sight of the specific context of the question.

Comment: You can also write `match="*[@type='async']/content"`

Comment: @MichaelKay I thought I did.

Comment: Need a new pair of specs.